# Can I use function-notation operator#() to call operator for built-in types?

Tags: c++, function, operators, operator-overloading

When I define my own data type I can also define operators on them by overloading the appropriate `operator`-functions globally:

```
struct Stuff {};

Stuff operator+(Stuff, Stuff) { return Stuff{}; }
```

I can then use it infix-like, but still can address it via the function-notation. So this is fine:

```
Stuff x;
Stuff y;
Stuff a = x+y;             // using infix-notation
Stuff b = operator+(x,y);  // using the function-notation
```

But with `int` (for example) there already *is* a `+` defined.

**Is there a way to call `int operator+(int,int)` (if I may refer to it this way) in the function-notation and not in the infix-notation?**

When I try

```
int aa = 12;
int bb = operator+(a, 6);    // err
int cc = ::operator+(a, 6);  // err
```

I get errors like "operator+ not defined". **Am I addressing the function wrongly or is this not possible for built-ins?**

*Bonus:* if I write a template I would have different behavior for different type arguments, then:

```
template<typename T>
T add_op(T a, T b) { return a+b; }

template<typename T>
T add_fun(T a, T b) { return operator+(a,b); } // failing for int

int main() {
    int am = add_op(3, 4);                 // ok
    int bm = add_fun(3, 4);                // fail
    Stuff um = add_op(Stuff{}, Stuff{});   // ok
    Stuff vm = add_fun(Stuff{}, Stuff{});  // ok
}
```

This seems rather strange and I wonder if there is a way to write `add_fun` using function-notation for `+`, or if I have to stick to the infix-`+` as a rule in templates.

Comment: you need to define a constructor for stuff taking an int then the int will automatically be converted to Stuff

Comment: Why would you want to use function call notation? Operator notation works for both cases.

Comment: the `operator+()` notation is not available for built-in types. And you can't change what `+` does on integers, floats, chars, etc.

Comment: @jrok I seem to remember one case years ago with much legacy code where there were operators defined in a namespace. And although it is possible `using` operators from those namespaces and then facilitate the infix-notation back then I used the qualifying `::`-scoping to be more clear what operator was used. i.e. `using namespace my::ops; a+b;` versus `my::ops::operator+(a,b);`. It is definitely not the best idea to put the operators there, I agree.

Comment: how are you going to distinguish between free and member operator+ at the call site? just using  `a+b` will do that for you, but using a function call syntax won't. And you can answer your question easily by trying it out in a compiler, so what is it that you are really after?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am after a concept here for explaining "how stuff works". And I guessed that I could address any operator this way. Luckily I tried out my guess and got skeptical. In consider my compiler not "authoritative" in everything, so I am looking for the right place in the standard.

Comment: @towi: If you have a rather recent compiler, or two, you can safely assume them being authorative enough for such basic things on language features that exist for two, maybe three decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't even define `operator+( int, int )`; at least one of
the operands of a user defined operator must be a user defined
type (class or enum type).

Logically, one might expect to be able to *call* these
functions using the `operator+` syntax, as the compiler does
consider them in overload resolution, *as if* they existed as
functions.  But §13.6 says clearly that they are only used in
overload resolution, and not in any other context.

> 13.6.(1) **Built-in operators** [over.built]
>
> The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators defined in Clause 5 are specified in this subclause. These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process as described in 13.3.1.2 *and are used for no other purpose*. ...

Comment: That much is clear. But why "not even"? To be able to *define* a thing may not be related to *use* a thing. I had guessed that I can address the built-in operators in function notation.

Comment: @towi Curiously, you can't.  One would have expected to be able
to use the function syntax to call them, since the compiler does
consider them in overload resolution _as if_ such functions
exist.  But §13.6 says clearly that these functions are only
used in overload resolution, and no where else.

Comment: Very good, thanks. Do you mind putting that into your answer, or shall I?